# Can I use ${file} to generate a output "arg" for a task in vscode?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to build files in vscode with an "unsupported" compiler. Therefore I've created a task to start the compiler and this works perfectly, as long as the source and destination files are given. I give my source file as `${file}` and vscode correctly substitutes this with the source file. For the destination file I have to use the same filename but change it's extension.

Is it possible for me to create a string variable in .json, copy the value of my `${file}` string into that and use change its extension before using it as an argument?

My tasks.json is below, my sourcefile `${file}` = "C:\_projects\Customer\Logging\LogAsync\ASyncLog\Server.kl"

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": ".\\ktrans.exe",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FANUC\\WinOLPC\\bin\\"
            },
            "args": [
                "${file}",
                "C:\\_projects\\Customer\\Logging\\LogAsync\\ASyncLog\\Server.pc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: use `${fileBasenameNoExtension}` and `${fileDirname}`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for helping. My working code is below for other peaple who came here searching for how to compile Fanuc Karel in vscode:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": ".\\ktrans.exe",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FANUC\\WinOLPC\\bin\\"
            },
            "args": [
                "${file}",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.pc" 
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use ${file} to generate an output "arg" for a task in vscode. To do so, simply add the following line to your tasks.json file:

"args": ["${file}"]